# Get data from controller and show it via AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to get data from a controller and display it in a html pop-up when a button is clicked.

At this point the POPUP is showing when the button is clicked but the data isn't loaded

At this point I need that onclick the values get loaded and show them in the popup.

index.blade.php

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" id ="uid" name="uid" value="<?php echo $user->id ?>">
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="card card-signup card-plain">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <div class="card-header card-header-primary text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                            <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="card-title">Editar</h4>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form" method="POST" action = "{{ route('/alteruser') }}" name = 'user'>
         @csrf

                         <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="form-group bmd-form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <div class="input-group-text">
                                            <i class="material-icons"></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input name = 'name' type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $seluser->id  ?? ''?>" id='id' disabled>
                                    <input name = 'name' type="text" class="form-control" "<?php echo $seluser->name  ?? ''?>" id='name'>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo $seluser->email  ?? ''?>" id = 'email'>
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="<?php echo $seluser->password  ?? ''?>" class="form-control" id = 'password'>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $seluser->nif  ?? ''?>" class="form-control" id = 'nif'>
                                   <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $seluser->contacto  ?? ''?>" class="form-control" id = 'contact'>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Grupo" class="form-control" id = 'grupo'>
                                </div>
                            </div>
   
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-link btn-wd btn-lg" name = 'uid'>Confirmar</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UserController@GetUser:

```
     public function getUser() {

    $id = $_POST['uid'];

    $seluser = DB::table('users') -> where('id', $id) -> first();

    $view = view('/users/index',compact('seluser'))->render();

    return response(['status'=> 1, 'data' => $view]);

  }
```

Ajax code in index.blade.php:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#uid").click(function (e){
              e.preventDefault();

              $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: baseUrl+"/getUser",
              data:{uid: $("#uid").val()},
              dataType: 'json',

              success: function(data) {
              $('#edit').html(data.html);
            }
              });
   });
});
```

I'm new at AJAX so i assume the error is in it

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You are not capturing a value to pass on your AJAX Call So try `data:{uid: $("#uid").val()`

Comment: Pretty sure that is you have looked at the browsers Developers Tools (F12) you would have seen an error if you have looked for it

Answer (score 0):

you should return response instead of view in controller like below

```
public function getUser()
{

    $_SESSION['getUser'] = 1;
    echo "AAA";

    $id = $_POST['uid'];

    $seluser = DB::table('users')
                -> where('id', $id)
                -> first();
    $view = view('/users/index',compact('seluser'))->render();
    return response(['html' => $view]);
}
```

and get response like below

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl+"/getUser",
    data:{uid:uid},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
       $('#edit').html(data.html);
   }
});
```

Comment: After updating my code the console shows me the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' at  if (data.status == 1)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63357347/get-data-from-controller-and-show-it-via-ajax#comment112032959_63357347

Comment: @Monika , thanks for your help. Now the console is returning this error:          Uncaught ReferenceError: $document is not defined
    at user:331

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly for your help, i've updated the code now, bur it gives me the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $document is not defined and I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: loose the `$` its a standard js object, not a jquery one so `document.ready(function(){`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've changed the code to `$(document).ready(function(){` and added the line `<script src="{{ asset('material') }}/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>`  and the error disappeard but it still don't display the data from the controller.

Comment: Did you fix `data:{uid:uid},` as per my comment above

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I did